# NoClassDefFound error when using java.sql classes in JMH test in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, jmh, sbt-jmh

If I create a minimal sbt project with a build.sbt that looks like

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.3.1"

enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

with `addSbtPlugin("pl.project14.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.4.6")` in `project/plugins.sbt`

and the following code in `src/main/scala/test/Test.scala`:

```scala
import java.sql._

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
class Test {

  var connection: Connection = null
}
```

Then when I run `sbt Jmh/compile` I get the following exception:

```
Writing out Java source to /home/thayne/sandbox/sbt-jmh-test/target/scala-3.3.1/src_managed/jmh and resources to /home/thayne/sandbox/sbt-jmh-test/target/scala-3.3.1/resource_managed/jmh
Annotation generator had thrown the exception.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Connection
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.reflection.RFClassInfo.getMethods(RFClassInfo.java:99)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.buildAnnotatedSet(BenchmarkGenerator.java:213)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.core.BenchmarkGenerator.generate(BenchmarkGenerator.java:77)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.generators.bytecode.JmhBytecodeGenerator.main(JmhBytecodeGenerator.java:100)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:144)
        at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:94)
        at sbt.Run.$anonfun$runWithLoader$5(Run.scala:121)
        at sbt.Run$.executeSuccess(Run.scala:187)
        at sbt.Run.runWithLoader(Run.scala:121)
        at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:128)
        at pl.project13.scala.sbt.JmhPlugin$.internalGenerateBenchmarkSourcesAndResources(JmhPlugin.scala:112)
        at pl.project13.scala.sbt.JmhPlugin$.$anonfun$generateBenchmarkSourcesAndResources$2(JmhPlugin.scala:96)
        at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$1(FileFunction.scala:81)
        at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$4(FileFunction.scala:154)
        at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:415)
        at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:395)
        at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$3(FileFunction.scala:150)
        at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:415)
        at sbt.util.Difference.apply(Tracked.scala:390)
        at sbt.util.FileFunction$.$anonfun$cached$2(FileFunction.scala:149)
        at pl.project13.scala.sbt.JmhPlugin$.generateBenchmarkSourcesAndResources(JmhPlugin.scala:98)
        at pl.project13.scala.sbt.JmhPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$12(JmhPlugin.scala:59)
        at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:63)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:69)
        at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:283)
        at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:24)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:292)
        at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:283)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Connection
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 42 more
```

It seems like the java.sql module isn't available during the compilation state for JMH, but JMH needs access to it for reflection. Is there any way to make it available during the compilation stage?

I'm using Java 21 (OpenJDK).

Comment: What happens if you add your specific database driver as a dependency to the project?

Comment: Same result. I excluded that to provide a minimal reproducible example.